# Sampling a number of observations according to a variable by group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, sampling

I would like to sample a dataset with a varying number of draws, according to a variable n (MWE) :

```
data<-data.frame(id = seq(1, 10000), group = sample(c(1:3), 100,replace = TRUE))
data<-data%>%mutate(n=group*2)
data<-data%>%group_by(group)%>%do(sample_n(.,n))
```

These lines worked back in 2020 but not now, I receive this message of error :

```
Error in `sample_n()`:
! Can't compute indices.
Caused by error in `size <= n || replace`:
! 'length = 3800' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I also tested the solution with map2 but with no success (and it is heavier).

EDIT: The answer of Mael works well with my MWE even with more rows and groups.

```
data<-data.frame(id = seq(1, 2000000), group = sample(c(1:10000), 2000000,replace = TRUE))
data<-data%>%mutate(n=group*2)
data<-data%>%group_by(group)%>%do(slice_sample(.,n=unique(.$n)))
```

However, with my dataset, I have a message of error when I apply the function to more than 223,000 rows (I searched for the limit; be it the rows between 1 and 224,000 or between 100,000 and 324,000), I have a message of error, see for example :

```
test<-bano_tirage[c(100000:300000),]
bano_sample<-test%>%group_by(nom_commune) %>%group_modify(~ slice_sample(.x, n = unique(.x$pop_contact)))
test<-bano_tirage[c(100000:3240000),]
bano_sample<-test%>%group_by(nom_commune) %>%group_modify(~ slice_sample(.x, n = unique(.x$pop_contact)))
Error in `slice_sample()`:
! `n` must be a round number, not an integer vector.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```